# Next Js rewrite not working when going back in browser

Tags: next.js

I'm rewriting `/editorial/bowers-and-wilkins` to `/bowers-and-wilkins` in my next.config.js:

```
async rewrites() {
  const fallback = [
    {
      source: "/:path*",
      destination: `/editorial/:path*`
    }
  ];

  const afterFiles = [
      {
        source: `/bowers-and-wilkins`,
        destination: `/editorial/bowers-and-wilkins`
      }
  ];

  return {
    fallback,
    afterFiles
  };
}
```

The redirect works, I'm using it in a Link component for example:

```
<Link href="/bowers-and-wilkins">
  <a>
    Bowers &amp; Wilkins
  </a>
</Link>
```

But when navigating to a different link then hitting back in the browser I get an incompatible href error:

> The provided as value (/bowers-and-wilkins) is incompatible with the
> href value (/editorial/[slug]).

Is there a workaround? I suspect may be modifying the Link or history state may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating from next 10 to 12.1.0 fixed my issue